# UITextfield can not autocomplete when running on device

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, uitextfield

I have a problem.It can auto complete when enter some text on simulator.But it can not auto complete like that when running on devices .

Device :Iphone 4 IOS 6.1

Xcode 4.6 IOS 6.1

Simulator output

[image]

Device output

[image]

Autocomplete.h
http://pastie.org/8120169

Autocomplete.m
http://pastie.org/8120171